# Get comments from Tiktok video using Tiktok display API

Tags: tiktok

I am able to get Tiktok videos of logged in user, but unable to search for a way in Tiktok API to get video list with comments too. It is just showing total comments count but not actual comments. Is it even possible to get the comments in Tiktok using its display API. Don't want to use unofficial scraper tools.

Comment: A api fornece um endpoint para isso, entretanto eu estou encontrando problema com a requisição, recebo um code 4002:

https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1738081151897602

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think TikTok is providing any API to get video comments.

https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/tiktok-api-v2-video-object

Here you can see that only 'comment_count' is available in the video object provided by TikTok query video through
https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/video/query/

so yeah getting whole comments is not possible using TikTok API.